# QGIS Polygonize tool error

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I am running into a error message with the Polygonize tool raster to vector.
In taking an online course the instructor is asking us to use the Polygonize tool on a reclassified raster of a NDVI (satelite red and NIR)

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'
Process returned error code 1**


Tool log:
QGIS version: 3.28.10-Firenze
QGIS code revision: e2edb9c468
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.7.1
GEOS version: 3.12.0-CAPI-1.18.0
PROJ version: Rel. 9.2.1, June 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.5.5 (git-version: f1a9ac)
Algorithm started at: 2023-09-17T15:41:07
Algorithm 'Polygonize (raster to vector)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False, 'EXTRA' : '', 'FIELD' : 'DN', 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/bhara/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kEpyjD/6e2676b46eb140a1935108436537e0da/OUTPUT.nc', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

GDAL command:
gdal_polygonize.bat C:/Users/bhara/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kEpyjD/6e2676b46eb140a1935108436537e0da/OUTPUT.nc -b 1 -f "Interlis 2" C:/Users/bhara/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kEpyjD/fd10321f179a44f081309b157608bb44/OUTPUT.xtf OUTPUT DN
GDAL command output:
Creating output C:/Users/bhara/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kEpyjD/fd10321f179a44f081309b157608bb44/OUTPUT.xtf of format Interlis 2.

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\gdal_argparse.py", line 175, in main 
self.doit(**kwargs) 
**File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py", line 314, in doit 
return gdal_polygonize(**kwargs) 
File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py", line 132, in gdal_polygonize 
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer( 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'
Process returned error code 1**

Execution completed in 0.19 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/bhara/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kEpyjD/fd10321f179a44f081309b157608bb44/OUTPUT.xtf'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/bhara/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kEpyjD/fd10321f179a44f081309b157608bb44/OUTPUT.xtf
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Comment: Output to a geopackage

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the Default output vector layer extension (in Settings->Options->Processing->General) to a value other than "xtf" e.g. to the value "gpkg" which is the default for such option.